# How to get 2D screen space area of 3D object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw on a 2D canvas on top of a three.js scene. I only want the stroke to paint if it is inside of the 3D object of the three.js scene.

What is the best way to get the 2D screen space area from a 3D object in three.js?

[Example of result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIYrZ.png)

I am thinking it is something to do with unprojecting with raycasting? but i'm not sure.

Any help the the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: cann't you do it  without 2d canvas? draw line in 3.js

Comment: I suggest rendering mask to texture and multiplying it by your stroke result. Raycaster doesn't seem like a right tool there for me.

Comment: I think what you want to do is set up three canvases. A normal scene with the mesh at the bottom, then a canvas to be drawn on on top of that. Then above that, the mask based on the mesh. There is a mask example in the examples folder, or https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_masking

Comment: @Radio Thanks! that looks like the right direction I need to go in. Much Appreciated